# json.loads with wrong format input string

Tags: python, json

What would be the fastest way (execution wise) to to `json.loads` on this sort of input string:

```
istr=""" {u'topic': u'dl_job', u'url': u'http://somedomain.com' }"""
```

I don't have much control over what is passed as `istr`.

NOTES:

- json.loads doesn't like the leading `u`
- nor does it like strings being delimited by `'` instead of `"`

**Updated:**  I know I could play dirty tricks like replacing the `u` and `'` but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your lack of control means that you might also have something like: `istr=""" {u'topic': u'dl_j"""`?

Comment: What you have is not json, so you can't really load it as json. If it's a Python data structure (it looks like one), you can use `ast.literal_eval`, but that won't like the missing `}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a Python data structure (as it looks like), the function you want is `ast.literal_eval`.

http://docs.python.org/library/ast#ast.literal_eval

This is similar to just calling `eval`, but literal_eval is safe, because it won't call any functions or anything, just parse literals (i.e. lists, dicts, strings, numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you can trust the input, eval() seems to be twise faster than naïve replace. The involved risk may not be worth of the performance gain, though. (EDIT: Thanks J.F. Sebastian / Thomas K, added [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) timing.)

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit(lambda: json.loads(istr.replace("'", "\"").replace("u\"", "\"")), number=10000)
0.69373106956481934

# UNSAFE
timeit(lambda: eval(istr), number=10000)
0.27783799171447754

# literal_eval accepts only strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None
timeit(lambda: ast.literal_eval(istr.strip()), number=10000)
0.4245460033416748
```

(I assumed the missing } in the end of istr was a typo.)

Comment: -1: don't use `eval()` on strings that you can't control. Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is JSON. It has a formal specification of what constitutes a valid JSON string. json.loads doesn't load python dictionaries from strings, it loads JSON from strings. Trying to load other things will mostly get you into trouble, and yes, lead to hacks.

If you're wanting to eval python dictionaries, I'd suggest Thomas K's comment, or just eval().